# Invalid typescript environment using vscode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, create-react-app

I am writing React app (started from create react app) with vscode, I am also using eslint. Recently I started to integrate Typescript.
For some reason I have problems to write some Typescript expressions. For example:

```
interface Lengthwise {
    length: number;
}

function loggingIdentity<T extends Lengthwise>(arg: T): T {
    console.log(arg.length);  // Now we know it has a .length property, so no more error
    return arg;
}
```

This example is taken from [typescriptlang.org page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).
I got the following error:
[image: vscode error]

Any idea what is wrong in my environment?

Comment: I'm going with the simple solution here: have you tried restarting the TS lang server and eslint?

Comment: Yes.. Didnt work.. Maybe I did it incorrect? How should I do it?

Comment: `F1` brings up a list of actions. I presume you have typescript-eslint installed? Otherwise eslint will try to parse it as plain JS, which obviously isn't what you want.

Comment: I installed @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin and @typescript-eslint/parser. How can I restart the ts lang server? f1 doesn't show any related action

Comment: If nothing else, reloading VS code would definitely work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually the issue was invalid parser in eslintrc.
Changed parser from 'babel-eslint' to @typescript-eslint/parser and it's worked.